# Resolving sub-dependency in DryIoc with a serviceKey fails

Tags: ioc-container, dryioc

I want to use a *serviceKey* to distinguish between different implementations of a service.

Code explanation: there is an ICat interface, which is used to "say" a cat's word "Meow". The word "Meow" comes from the implementation of ISoundProducer (it is injected into an implementation of ICat).

I register two services (ICat and ISoundProducer) with the same serviceKey = "x". After that I try to resolve an ICat instance, but it fails.

Here is the demo code:

```
using DryIoc;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Container ioc = new Container();
        ioc.Register<ISoundProducer, GoodCatSoundProducer>(serviceKey: "x");
        ioc.Register<ICat, GoodCat>(serviceKey: "x");

        var c1 = ioc.Resolve<ICat>("x");
        c1.Say();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface ISoundProducer
{
    string ProduceSound();
}

public class GoodCatSoundProducer : ISoundProducer
{
    string ISoundProducer.ProduceSound() => "Meow";
}

public interface ICat
{
    void Say();
}

public class GoodCat : ICat
{
    private ISoundProducer _soundProducer;
    public GoodCat(ISoundProducer soundProducer) => this._soundProducer = soundProducer;
    void ICat.Say() => Console.WriteLine(_soundProducer.ProduceSound());
}
```

This gives me an exception:

> Unable to resolve ISoundProducer as parameter "soundProducer"   in
>   GoodCat: ICat {ServiceKey="x"}   from container   with normal and
>   dynamic registrations:   x, {ID=28, ImplType=GoodCatSoundProducer}}

What am I doing wrong? How can I resolve a service with another injected service, while they both have the same serviceKey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the key of dependency:

```
ioc.Register<ICat, GoodCat>(serviceKey: "x",
  made: Made.Of(Parameters.Of.Type<ISoundProducer>(serviceKey: "x")));
ioc.Register<ISoundProducer, GoodCatSoundProducer>(serviceKey: "x");
```

Comment: For some reason it does not help. I still get completely same error.

Comment: Huh sorry, I have reverted cat - sound producer relationship. Now should work.

Comment: Yes, now it works, and I see how to use it now. Thanks a lot :)